# How can I request MIDI device permission on Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, midi, web-midi

I have a MIDI device (launchpad) that I want to use with an Electron application. I was able to read events on the MIDI device using Microsoft Edge Chromium using Web MIDI API (https://github.com/djipco/webmidi). However, in order to start reading the MIDI device, permissions needed to be set, and displayed like so:

[image: Permission]

When I run `npm start` to start the electron project, I cannot find a way to enable permissions for MIDI devices. I cannot see any of my MIDI devices, and I am assuming that is because I am missing permissions.

I have researched the Electron documentation, and was not able to find anything. `systemPreferences` provides a way to request permissions, but for camera and microphone, not MIDI devices (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences).

Thank you very much, and any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Could you move to using https://github.com/justinlatimer/node-midi instead? I used this recently for an electron project and it works well on all platforms. It means not running the midi in BrowserWindow though.

Answer (score 1):

we can handle this using [ses.setPermissionRequestHandler](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session#sessetpermissionrequesthandlerhandler).

Comment: I put `mainWindow.webContents.session.setPermissionRequestHandler(
        function permissionRequestHandler(webContents, permission, callback) {
         return callback(true);
        }
      );` after `mainWindow.loadURL(url);` and I still did not get the permission request. I read the documentation, but I was not able to understand it very well, so I looked for other code online, and that was what I was able to get. Am I missing something? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: From my understanding, that handles the permission once called, but does not actually call the permission

Comment: In this handler we can get the permissions and based on the permissions you can handle it. If you need a deep knowledge you can refer opensource wavebox code. They are handling it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement two handlers in your main process for the window where you're enabling WebMidi:

```js
  mainWindow.webContents.session.setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback, details) => {
    console.log('Permission request:', permission);

    if (permission === 'midi' || permission === 'midiSysex') {
      callback(true);
    } else {
      callback(false);
    }
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.session.setPermissionCheckHandler((webContents, permission, requestingOrigin) => {
    console.log('Permission check:', permission);

    if (permission === 'midi' || permission === 'midiSysex') {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
```

Then you can enable WebMidi like:

```js
WebMidi.enable({ sysex: true });
```